# SQL(ite) JOIN with regex within JOIN

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite, join

I have two tables both with a column called `Name`. Sometimes the names begin with an uppercase letter whereas other times not. I would like to join the two tables on the names so that bob's match the Bob's. I assume that this could be possible with regular expressions, so how can one construct an SQL JOIN query that does do this match and what is the correct regex?

For example: Say I have table1 as :

```
Name| col1
----------
Bob | a
Jon | b
```

and table 2 as:

```
Name| col2
----------
bob| c
Jon| d
```

I would join them as follows (with xx being the missing regex and yy being the correct selection)

```
SELECT * , yy as NameWithCapAtFront
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
ON xx(t1.Name)=xx(t2.Name)
```

but this misses the `bob` match with `Bob`.

Further, how would one always select capitalised version of the Name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using the `lower()` function?

```
SELECT *, upper(substr(t1.name, 1, 1) || lower(t1.name, 2) as NameWithCapAtFront
FROM table1 as t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 as t2
     ON lower(t1.Name) = lower(t2.Name);
```

Admittedly, this lower cases the whole name, but that seems reasonable in this case.

Comment: Is this true on SQL Server? I don't remember SQL Server being case sensitive on joins like that

Comment: @JeffOrris . . . Whether or not any given database uses case sensitive comparisons depends on the collation for the table, database, and server.  By default, I don't think joins are case sensitive in most databases (I would say all), but it appears to be an issue for this OP.